# vscode: Find which extension installed a given theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

For testing (and to have some fun) I installed a number of themes for Visual Studio Code but I want to remove some of them. I know I can guess the corresponding extension name from the theme name, but some extensions contain multiple themes and their name is not always easy to trace back: is there a way to figure out which extension/package installed a given theme?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Extensions => select extension => Contributions

Comment: You'll probably want theme picker to stay opened for some time: `"workbench.quickOpen.closeOnFocusLost": false`